# How do I add whitespace before and after parenthesis?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use the `.replace()` or `.replaceAll()` method to add space between operators. Basically, I've made my code to read infix strings and distinguish/check elements based on the white space. For example `(3+3)` will spit me an error, but `( 3 + 3 )` can be computed by my program. I'm having trouble with this input:

```
!(!((5-10)*(4-(9/2)) > 60)-(((5*7)/(4/(5+3)))=15))<((4-3)=1)
```

I have coded:

```
input[i] = input[i].replace("(", "( ").replace(")", " )").replace("!", "! ")
                   .replaceAll("(\\S)/(\\S)", "(\\d) / (\\d)");
```

I have only started on the division part for this (the other `replace()` methods are for simpler test cases). But it replaces my `9/2` with `(d) / (d)` when I convert it to a postfix expression. I could really use some help with the regex.

**Edit 1:**

```
input[i] = input[i].replaceAll("([()!])(?! )", "$1 ").replaceAll("([()!])(?<=(\\d))\\)", " $1");
```

My second replaceAll() is supposed to find a closing parenthesis preceded by a digit. But it's functioning properly. Did I code it incorrectly?

Comment: Either you miss on the requirements, or I didn't understand you. What's wrong with just .replace("(", " ( ").replace(")", " ) ")? This would give you blanks around all parentheses.

Comment: Why? Why not write yourself a proper scanner and avoid the whole problem?

Comment: In your `Edit 1:` also provide your input as well as expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Your multiple `replace` methods can be reduced to single `replaceAll` using **character class**, also your `replaceAll` needs to use back-reference properly:

```
input[i] = input[i].replaceAll("([()!])(?! )", "$1 ")
                   .replaceAll("(\\d+)/(\\d+)", "$1 / $2");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But what does [()]! refer to? I know the other syntax in the code, just not quite sure what you're doing there.

Comment: `[()!]` is a character class. [Read more about it](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: All right, I have added a first edit. Thanks for your help in advance.